# Разделить строку на числа и строки Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

У меня есть строка `"12345ABC7DE89FG012AB"` и её необходимо разделить на подстроки `["12345","ABC","7","DE","89","FG","012","AB"]`. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: критерий деления не ясен. чем, например, строка "89" отличается от строки "DE". только составом входящих в них символов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то вроде того:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String str = "12345ABC7DE89FG012AB";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+|\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            result.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println(String.join(", ", result));
    }

}
```